# Python 3.6.3: Don't understand how to fix IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

This script is made to read a filename and file path from a text document, print the filename, and then run the file. The file is progs.conf, and it looks like this:

```
[prog.1]
Name:NotepadPlusPlus
Path:C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe
```

The script is:

```
import subprocess

progList = open("progs.conf", "r")
numLines = sum(1 for line in progList)

repeatTimes = numLines / 3
counter = 0

while counter <= repeatTimes:
    print("Opening " + str(progList.readlines()[counter + 1][6:]) + "...")
    subprocess.Popen(str(progList.readlines()[counter + 2][6:]))
    counter = counter + 1
```

And it spits out this error:

> File launcher.py", line 16, in
>
> print("Opening " + str(progList.readlines()[counter + 1][6:]) + "...")
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) . This type of error happens if you index into a list _after_ its end. Output counter and see how many lines are in proglist.

Comment: What is `len(progList.readlines())`? What is `counter + 1`?

Comment: you should increment counter by 3 not 1, among other errors. Every *3rd* line from the 2nd has the program title. Assuming no blank lines between blocks

Comment: You are calling `progList.readlines()` multiple times, without reopening or rewinding the file.  None of those are actually reading anything (so there are no valid indexes into the list), because you entirely exhausted the file in the line that calculated `numLines`.  Read the file *once*, do all your calculations and loops on the resulting list.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't have to `readlines` so many times
2. Your counter counting is wrong,

*I'm not on windows so I edited your conf file slightly*

Consider this

```
import subprocess

with open("progs.conf", "r") as progList:
    lines = progList.readlines()
    ilines = iter(lines)
    sets = zip(ilines,ilines,ilines)
    for bname, prog, path in sets:
        print "Processing " + str(bname)
        print "Launching " + str(prog.split(":")[1])
        print "PAth: " + path.split(":")[1]
        subprocess.Popen(str(path.split(":")[1]), shell=True)
```

And the conf file was as below

```
$ cat progs.conf
[prog.1]
Name:NotepadPlusPlus
Path:gvim
```

### Explanation

```
lines = progList.readlines()
ilines = iter(lines)
```

Read the file once and make an iterator for the read list of lines.

You can then do `sets = zip(ilines,ilines,ilines)` to store this sequence in groups of 3. `for bname, prog, path in sets:` iterates over this list of groups of 3. Done.